# Css class not identified by IE 10 in compatibility mode

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer-10

I have the following css class which works fine in IE10 with compatibility mode OFF. But when I test this page with Compatibility mode 'ON', the css class is ignored. What this class does is basically set a background color for the table row.

```
.TMDarkBlue
{
    color: White;
    background: #2895D5;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The HTML for the datagrid where I have used this is as follows.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgResults" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="2" PageSize="15" ForeColor="Black" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="10" PagerStyle-NextPageText="&gt;">
    <PagerStyle NextPageText="Next" CssClass="pagerStyle" PrevPageText="Prev" HorizontalAlign="Justify" Position="Top" Wrap="False" Mode="NumericPages" ForeColor="#2D4374" Font-Overline="False"></PagerStyle>
    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="itemStyle"></ItemStyle>
    <AlternatingItemStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="alternateRow"></AlternatingItemStyle>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="TMDarkGray" ForeColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="TMDarkGray" Wrap="False" />
    <EditItemStyle Wrap="False" />
    <SelectedItemStyle CSSClass="TMOrangeHighlight" Wrap="False" BackColor="#2D4374" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

I am new to web frontend developing so please pardon me if I have missed some important info here. Let me know what additional details are needed and I will update this question accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
 table tr.TMDarkBlue td {
         background-color: #2895D5;
          color: white;
          font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Comment: You may need to collapse border of your table cells to spread background seamless across the rows.

Comment: Do I have to change my HTML for this class? I mean in the datagrid I use  <HeaderStyle CssClass="TMDarkGray" ForeColor="White" />. Do I have to change anything there?

Comment: Can you give an example of the outputed html

Comment: @Mr_Green: Thanks for the comment. Removing the forecolor displays my the text in default (black) color but does not have any effect on the background color.

Comment: @Mark: I am working on the outputed html sample. Basically it is a datagrid with dark blue header row. The TMDarkBlue class sets the background color of the header row to Dark Blue with text in white color. The obvious solution which I tried and works was to remove the CSS class altogether and add backColor = #2895D5. Although this works but it defeats the purpose of CSS. So I am looking for a solution in which I can still make use of CSS. Hope this helps

Comment: @Coder sorry, I can't understand. which effect you are talking about related to background color?

Comment: @Mr_Green: Sorry, let me explain. The desired output is a table with header row with Dark Blue background color and white text. My problem is in IE10 with compatibility mode on, the css class is ignored and hence the background color is not changed to Dark Blue. As per your solution, removing the foreground = white, does not help to change the background color.

Comment: @Coder I think you should not use css here. Instead use `BackColor` attibute to `ItemStyle` tag or some other element. (_I am not good with asp.net_)

Comment: @Mr_Green,@Mark: Thank you for all your suggestions. I think I will just use the BackColor attribute for now.